# Create .txt file out from SQL statement

Tags: sql-server

I try to make a SQL statement to create a `.txt` file for each id that added to database, but this not working. I try this:

```
DECLARE @FileName varchar(50), @bcpCommand varchar(2000) 
SET @FileName = REPLACE('G:\'+CONVERT(char(8),GETDATE(),1)+'.txt','/','-') 
SET @bcpCommand = 'bcp "SELECT * FROM dbo.dbTest WHERE (DATEADD(MINUTE,-1420, GETDATE())) < [date];" queryout "' 
SET @bcpCommand = @bcpCommand + @FileName + '" -U garth -P pw -c' 
PRINT @bcpCommand
```

and of course I need this result savede in G:/, but this not working for me. My db name are testDB

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean you want to create a bcp file for each database?  Simply loop over all the databases, and ensure you specify the database name parameter for your bcp statement so it knows what database to execute the queryout query in.  One other thing you will need to fix though, is the filename.  You can modify it below to append the db name to the output file, so you do not end up overwriting each results.

```
DECLARE @FileName varchar(50), @bcpCommand varchar(2000) 
declare @x int = 5
declare @y int
declare @dbname varchar(100)
select @y = max(database_id) from sys.databases

while @x <= @y
begin
select @dbname = name from sys.databases where database_id = @x
if @dbname is not null
begin
    SET @FileName = REPLACE('G:\'+CONVERT(char(8),GETDATE(),1) +'.txt','/','-') 
    SET @bcpCommand = 'bcp "SELECT * FROM dbo.dbTest WHERE (DATEADD(MINUTE,-1420, GETDATE())) < [date];" queryout "' 
    SET @bcpCommand = @bcpCommand + @FileName + '" -U garth -P pw -c -d"' + @dbname + '"'
    PRINT @bcpCommand
end
set @x = @x + 1
end
```

Sample results:

```
bcp "SELECT * FROM dbo.dbTest WHERE (DATEADD(MINUTE,-1420, GETDATE())) < [date];" queryout "G:\05-16-15.txt" -U garth -P pw -c -d"db1"
bcp "SELECT * FROM dbo.dbTest WHERE (DATEADD(MINUTE,-1420, GETDATE())) < [date];" queryout "G:\05-16-15.txt" -U garth -P pw -c -d"db2"
bcp "SELECT * FROM dbo.dbTest WHERE (DATEADD(MINUTE,-1420, GETDATE())) < [date];" queryout "G:\05-16-15.txt" -U garth -P pw -c -d"db3"
bcp "SELECT * FROM dbo.dbTest WHERE (DATEADD(MINUTE,-1420, GETDATE())) < [date];" queryout "G:\05-16-15.txt" -U garth -P pw -c -d"db4"
```